# Add sign up condition to devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My goal is simple. I want to allow a user to sign up only if he possesses a unique secret code. I would like to check if this code is valid (being in my secret codes database) and then delete it once the user signed up.

**I have a secret_code model with:**

```
:secret_code column
```

**I have a input for the secret code in my sign up form**

```
<%= f.input :secret_code, required: true, autofocus: true %>
```

Should I personalize the `class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`?

**How ?** Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by overriding registrationcontroller. Uncomment create method like this.

`def create
    super
end`

and add a filter like:

`before_action :check_secret_code, only: [:create]`

and you must modify your routes to tell devise use your controller instead of its default:

`devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }`

you can specify what you want in that `check_secret_code` method and make `render 'new'` if code is wrong. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Mehmet ! It is almost working. The only thing is that the `render 'new'` is giving an argument error on my html.erb form : First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty on `<%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>`. Do you know what could be the cause ?

Comment: Probably you can solve this by uncommenting the new action. but i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a simple `before filter`. This way you don't have to mess with devise code.

```
   class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      before_filter :check_conditions, only: :create

      def create
        super
      end

      private
        def check_conditions
          #your conditions
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Along to @Mehmet answer I had to cutomize `application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
 def resource_name
   :user
 end

 def resource
   @user ||= User.new
 end
 def devise_mapping
   @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
 end
end
```

And put `include ApplicationHelper after the class name` in `registrations_controller.rb`